# What $n$ s.t. this topology satisfies the separation axiom $T_n$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the real with the topology $T = \{ U \subset\mathbb{R}\:|\:0\notin U\text{ or }\mathbb{R}\setminus U\text{ finite}\} $. What is the largest value for $n \in \{0,1,2,3,3\frac{1}{2},4\}$ such that $X$ satisfies the separation axiom $T_n$?

First of all, the open sets in this topology are all cofinite sets and open intervals $I \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. I would argue that the topology is hausdorff, by using only the open intervals (without using the cofinite sets) to find open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$  for some $a,b \in X$. But I'm not sure if I could go any higher into $T_3$.

Comment: You need a bit more care for the Hausdorff property, not all open intervals are in your topology.

Comment: That works of $a,b\in X\setminus \{0\}$ but what if $a=0$?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker. Indeed, all open intervals not containing $0$ are excluded. But that does not change that for every point $p$ in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ there is an open inteval containing $p$. If this is right, isn't this also the property which quarantees Hausdorff?

Comment: @omar It takes two to tango and verify Hausdorfness... You have to show that any two points can be separated by disjoint neighborhoods. One of these points can be $0$.

Comment: Suppose $a=0$, then the only possible open sets containing $a$ are the cofinite sets. Let $U$ be some open set such that $a \in U$ and $X \setminus U$ finite. Is there then still any point left which has a disjunct open neighborhood $V$? Because Hausdorff requires $U$ and $V$ disjunct it should be that $V \subset X \setminus U$; but that's not possible..?

Comment: @omar Wlog let $x\neq 0$. Then $\{x\}$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{x\}$ separate $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker. Aha! That's what Brian said.. I totally mixed up open intervals and subsets of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Right.. So we take the singleton set (!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the open sets are **all** subsets of $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ together with all cofinite sets. You’re right that $X$ is Hausdorff, but since you described the topology incorrectly, you need to think a little more about how to show this.

Note that $X$ is compact. If $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is some $U_0\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $0\in U_0$. Now $X\setminus U_0$ is finite, so only finitely other elements of $\mathscr{U}$ are needed to complete a subcover.

HINT: What do you know about the separation properties of compact Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Well, compact Hausdorff spaces have some properties yes.. But am I allowed to utilize such properties when trying to prove some space Hausdorff? I would think that one should just try covering all possibilities for disjunct open neighborhoods for any two points?

Comment: @omar: Obviously you can’t use those properties to prove that $X$ is $T_2$, and I wasn’t suggesting that you should. **After** you prove that $X$ is $T_2$, which does indeed require looking at two cases, **then** you use what you know about compact $T_2$-spaces to say something about the higher separation properties.

Comment: *Corollary: If $A$ and $B$ are disjunct closed subsets of a compact Hausdorff space $X$, then there exist disjunct open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$.*

Comment: @omar: Yes: it’s $T_4$.

Answer (score 0):

The possible values of $n$ are 0,1.

Proof of $X$ satisfies $T_1$ axiom: Let $x,y\in X$, $x\neq y$. Then
$$U=X\setminus \{y\}, \quad V=X\setminus \{x\}$$
satisfies $x\in U\not\ni y$, $y\notin V \ni y$. And $U$ is neighborhood of $x$ and $V$ is neighborhood of $y$.

Proof of $X$ is not $T_2$ : Let $x,y\in X$, $x\neq y$. If $U$ is neighborhood of $X$ such that does not contain element $y$. If $y$ has neighborhood $V$ disjoint form $U$, We get $V$ is uncountable and $V\subset X\setminus U$. But $V\subset X\setminus U$ is finite and we get contradiction.

Comment: Wlog let $x\neq 0$. Then $\{x\}$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{x\}$ separate $x$ and $y$.